# what is the syntax of 'unarchive' of the jenkins workflow plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I see multiple usages of `unarchive` in the [tutorial of the Jenkins workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md).
But I'm not able to find any documentation about its syntax and options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [usage blurb in the snippet generator](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/e3c2c9c1a07c54d77409a1d8367da99b901765a6/basic-steps/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/ArtifactUnarchiverStep/config.jelly#L29-40):

> May take a `mapping` parameter which is a map from artifact names (files, directories ending in `/`, or any other Ant patternsets), to workspace destination names.
>
> For example to copy one file:
> `unarchive mapping: ['target/my.war': 'here.war']`
>
> To copy a whole directory:
> `unarchive mapping: ['dir/' : '.']`

Comment: It would be useful to provide some version context as well, "As of v1.X of the Workflow plugin..."

Comment: thanks, with that I also found why I was not able to see find the step in the Snippet generator - the name is just so different from what I have expected. https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/e3c2c9c1a07c54d77409a1d8367da99b901765a6/basic-steps/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/ArtifactUnarchiverStep.java#L36

Comment: Step titles definitely need to be reviewed in batch. Have not gotten to it yet.

Comment: Note that the snippet generator now just shows the step names, rather than the descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

As of [1.10](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/CHANGES.md#110-aug-31-2015) this step is deprecated. You should now use `stash` and `unstash`, which have a simpler syntax.

Comment: What if you want to create a permanent archive after a build step but before a deploy step. Wouldn't it better to use 'archive/unarchive' for that, since the "stash" is removed at the end up the pipeline?

Comment: Or to access files from a previous build for comparison.  [un]stash satisfies a common usage for [un]archive, but not persistence or sharing files between jobs.

Comment: Correct, there are some less common use cases for `unarchive`.

Comment: I want to retrieve an archived build from a previous run, as i may not have created the item i need in the current run. I can't do that with [un]stash. [un]archive was there for that purpose. Why was it deprecated?

Comment: Answering my own comment from above, the right command would be `copyArtifact`.

Comment: The docs recommend against `stash` for amounts of data larger than ~50MB. Since we are blessed with tooling like nodejs, we need something else where we might _want_ to use `stash`.

Comment: If you are referring to https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/pull/43, this is less significant if you run https://plugins.jenkins.io/artifact-manager-s3/, and anyway `archiveArtifacts` plus `unarchive` is no better (and possibly worse, since it does not automatically clean up files as promptly).